# Expansion of variables in double square brackets

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using bash 5.0.7, and hope that I can expand the variable `And="&&"` and `Or="||"` in the double square brackets:

```
$ [[ 1 > 0 $And 1 < 0 ]] 
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `$And`
$ [[ 1 > 0 ${And} 1 < 0 ]] 
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `${And}`
```

I hope there's a way to do this because that will largely simplify one of my codes. And also, any explanations will be highly appreciated: I am really curious about how `sh`/`bash` works! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without `eval` (which might involve quoting hell with the other parts of your test). Can you show what you're trying to achieve in the end? Perhaps there might be some other way to do what you want.

Comment: I'm really skeptical that would simplify your code. But if you're curious how bash works, then please notice that `[[ a > b ]]` will do a lexicographical comparison on its operands: `[[ 2 > 11 ]] && echo 2 is greater than 11` (and to add insult to injury, they'll do it using the current locale ;-)).

Comment: Even though it will be more verbose code, you're going to be better off just using an `if` or `case` based on `$And` rather than trying to shoe-horn it into the `[[` command.

Comment: I want my script to run between certain time, for example between 10am to 9:30pm: `start=100000; end=213000`. The problem is when `end` is over midnight, e.g. `end=020000`, I want `$now` to be larger than `$start` **OR** smaller than `$end` instead of **AND**. Is there another nonverbose way to do it?

Comment: If `end` before `start`, add 24h to `end`. If `now` before `start`, add 24h to `now`. Then compare.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I also want to compare them with `$now`.

Comment: @Student What stops you?

Comment: Then I should decide if to add 24h to `$now` based on if it is larger than `$start`. 
I ended up writing another function `if_within()` to make the code in `main()` clearer..

Answer (score 1):

It works with the `test` and `[` builtin and `-a` (for `&&`) and `-o` (for `||`):

```
$ and_or=-a
$ [ 1 -gt 0 $and_or 1 -lt 0 ] && echo yes || echo nope
nope
$ test 1 -gt 0 $and_or 1 -lt 0 && echo yes || echo nope
nope
$ and_or=-o
$ [ 1 -gt 0 $and_or 1 -lt 0 ] && echo yes || echo nope
yes
$ test 1 -gt 0 $and_or 1 -lt 0 && echo yes || echo nope
yes
```

(tested with bash 3.2.57 / 4.4.12 / 5.0.3)

As pointed out in the comments, I replaced the lexicographic comparison operators `>` and `<` with its arithmetic versions `-gt` and `-lt`.

But I would say this is quite a hack...

Comment: I always regard `[` as a more primitive version of `[[` so I did not expect that. Probably I should change my point of view..

Comment: @Student In some sense the approach works because `[` is more primitive. In general it's a command or a builtin (the latter in Bash), so it gets its arguments like any other external command: they are processed in the shell before the command even runs and *any* of them can be taken from a variable. `[[` is a *keyword* in Bash. It *alters* the parser: up to the next `]]` the rules are somewhat different. This is obviously more complex.